# Can a 7th-level Slayer activate Assassinate via a swift action Study, or must it still be a standard action?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, assassin

I just got to 10th level for my Dwarven Slayer and I can choose a new Advanced Slayer talent. I want to take Assassinate but I wanted something clarified.

At 7th level you can Study a target as a swift action but in the Assassinate description it says you need to take a standard action's worth of studying in order for that target to be assassinate-able. Can I use my swift action to study the target I want to assassinate or do I absolutely need to spend a standard action to "activate" the assassinate ability?

Answer (score 3):

### You must use a standard action.

They are two different abilities. [Studied Target](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/slayer/#TOC-Studied-Target-Ex-), initially a move action, is used as a **Swift Action** (7th level and on) so you can gain the ability bonuses:

> The slayer then gains a +1 bonus on Bluff, Knowledge, Perception, Sense Motive, and Survival checks attempted against that opponent and a +1 bonus on weapon attack and damage rolls against it. The DCs of slayer class abilities against that opponent increase by 1.

While [Assassinate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/slayer/slayer-talents/paizo-slayer-talents-advanced/assassinate) not only requires you to be able to make a **Sneak Attack**, but also spend your **Standard Action** to study the target for *this attack* specifically, before finally attacking.

If you try to *Assassinate* (standard, then attack) a *studied target* (swift action), the **Fortitude DC** for your *Assassinate* ability is increased as well (by +3 at 10th level).